# Linking to library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks, shared-libraries

I installed `ImageMagick` through `MacPorts`. So all `library` files are in `/opt/local/lib` and headers in `/opt/local/include/ImageMagick`. It works OK on my mac. In xCode `Build Settings - > Search Paths` everything looks to be set OK.

[image]

Added `library` files to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`

[image]

When I build my app it looks to be working. But when I try to run builded app on other computer where ImageMagick is not installed there comes this error message:

[image]

How can I fix it to make users to be able use my app without needing to additionally install ImageMagick and so on? How to link it that needed library files would come with my app (in project bundle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No support for it from ImageMagick forum, no support from StackOverflow, so I guess its impossible...

Answer (score 2):

Af of now your linking library is referred from /opt/local/lib/ ---

Solution for your issue:

1. Make sure where ever app is installed suport library is installed to right location
2. Carry the dynamic library with app bundle and refere the dyld from the app bundle which will be relative to app bundle launch path.

Update: If you are looking for the second option --- With this option your library will be placed inside your app bundle ... so app can refer the library from the app bundle.

1. The precompiled dynamic library can be carried with the application -- in xCode --> Go to Build Phases for the target --> Build Phase (copy files) ... this will make sure your dynamic library is copied to into your  app bundle ...
2. Update “install name” inside each dynamic library --- You can use 'otool' command to know present install path of your precompiled library and you can precompiled library install path using'install_name_tool' command in your terminal.

Comment: Maby I misunderstood you, but... 
1. I installed ImageMagick using MacPorts. All libraries installed using MacPorts is placed at `/opt/local/...`. So if app user is "home user" he really don't have MacPorts and directory `/opt` doesn't even exist at his computer. 
2.`refere the dyld from the app bundle which will be relative to app bundle launch path.`. Maby you could explain this step? I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: For clarity: option 2 basically means that you'll include the ImageMagick library in your application bundle and refer to that library instead of the one installed in `/opt/local/lib`. When using this approach, users of your app don't have to install the ImageMagick library themselves.